# Shell script to fetch S3 bucket size with AWS CLI

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli

I have this script that fetches all the buckets in AWS along with the size. But when I am running the script its fetching the bucket, but when running the loop for fetching the size, its throwing error. can someone point me where I am going wrong here. bcos when I am running the awscli commands for individual bucket, its fetching the size without any issues.
The desired output wille be as below, but for all the buckets, I have fetched for one bucket.
Desired ouptut:

```
aws --profile aws-stage s3 ls s3://<bucket> --recursive --human-readable --summarize | awk END'{print}'
   Total Size: 75.1 KiB
```

Error:

```
 Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:(s3|s3-object-lambda):[a-z\-0-9]*:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-.]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
aws_profile=('aws-stage' 'aws-prod');

#loop AWS profiles
for i in "${aws_profile[@]}"; do
    echo "${i}"
    buckets=$(aws --profile "${i}" s3 ls s3:// --recursive | awk '{print $3}')

    #loop S3 buckets
    for j in "${buckets[@]}"; do
        echo "${j}"
        aws --profile "${i}" s3 ls s3://"${j}" --recursive --human-readable --summarize | awk END'{print}'
    done

done
```

Comment: What is the expected otput of this?

Comment: What's the output of the `echo "${j}"` command?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary the expected output should be something like below, but for all the buckets, i have just ran for one.
aws --profile aws-stage s3 ls s3://<bucket> --recursive --human-readable --summarize | awk END'{print}'
   Total Size: 75.1 KiB

Comment: @Paolo The output for echo "${j}" I am getting all the buckets that are present in my aws account

Comment: Please post a sample desired output (that you get when executing the command in your terminal for instance) and edit your question

Comment: @Devops-Learner show that in the question

Comment: can you add `set -x` at the beggining of your script to see if your variables are properly populated ?

Comment: The way you define `buckets`, it's a single string rather than an array, so accessing it like an array (with `"${buckets[@]}"`) won't do anything useful. `set -x` will clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

aws_profiles=('aws-stage' 'aws-prod');

for profile in "${aws_profiles[@]}"; do
    echo "$profile"
    read -rd "\n" -a buckets <<< "$(aws --profile "$profile" s3 ls | cut -d " " -f3)"
    for bucket in "${buckets[@]}"; do
        echo "$bucket"
        aws --profile "$profile" s3 ls s3://"$bucket" --human-readable --summarize | awk END'{print}'
    done
done
```

The problem was that your `buckets` was a single string, rather than an array.